# Limit asp.net open session

Tags: asp.net, session

I have an asp.net application that can (theoretically) be deployed on several servers.

As part of a licensing mechanism, I would like to limit the number of open sessions globally.

i.e. the total number of open sessions on all servers cannot be over a certain amount (the amount is dependant on the licensing).

How can I achieve that?
I have no problem using 3rd party components (Free or paid)

Few constraints:

1. Any server can be shut down at any time.
2. I have to assume that the servers are on a closed intranet network (i.e. no outside internet)

Answer (score 0):

please check the answer under this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922502/limit-only-one-session-per-user-in-asp-net). it explains limiting one session per user but you can change it according to your needs

Comment: Thanks but it is a solution for only one server. When I have several then I have Application/Session dictionaries that have to be synced together across multiple servers.

Comment: how about using a database table? you can keep track of open sessions in a shared database table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Application` object to keep count of open session and use `Application.Start` and `session.start` events of `global.asax` to manage this count and manege open session count.