# how to allow only one active session per user

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, authentication, global-asax

I want to implement a code that enables only one session per user.
I use asp.net with forms authentication .

I read this post:
[Limit only one session per user in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922502/limit-only-one-session-per-user-in-asp-net)

but I want to do the opposite, to disconnect all previous sessions.

here is my code:

> ```
> void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
> {
>     Application["UsersLoggedIn"] = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>(); }
> ```

when user logs in, I insert a record : username, sessionID.
if the username exists, I just update the sessionID

```
    void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> d = HttpContext.Current.Application["UsersLoggedIn"] as System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>;
        if (d != null)
        {
            if (d.Count > 0)
            {
                    string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
                    {
                        if (d.ContainsKey(userName))
                        {
                            if (d[userName] != HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID)
                            {
                                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                                Session.Abandon();
                            }
                        }
                    }
}
}
```

but I get empty HttpContext.Current.User.
I tried also "AuthenticatedRequest", but then I get null Session.

any idea please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access HttpContext.Current.User and Session, you should use the `AcquireRequestState` event.

Answer (score 3):

If you're in a load balanced situation with multiple servers at place you'll want to persist this in some way, the problem comes when you need to release the user lock (either on termination of the users session or logout).