# Allow only a single login session per user

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-identity-2

Essentially I am asking [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903574/when-the-same-user-id-is-trying-to-log-in-on-multiple-devices-how-do-i-kill-the), but I am using ASP Identity instead of the ASP.Net Membership provider, and with that, that answer is of no use to me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922502/limit-only-one-session-per-user-in-asp-net

Comment: possible duplicate of [When the same user ID is trying to log in on multiple devices, how do I kill the session on the other device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903574/when-the-same-user-id-is-trying-to-log-in-on-multiple-devices-how-do-i-kill-the)

Comment: The answer you referenced is pretty much what you need to do. The references to Membership are minimal & you should easily be able to change them to Identity.

Comment: Turns out you are right, but after a few more hours digging, i found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487322/what-is-asp-net-identitys-iusersecuritystampstoretuser-interface). Won't this help with the situation without any database manipulation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do it. On login I call this:

```
var key = user.UserName;
var timeOut = new TimeSpan(0, 0, HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout, 0, 0);
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(key, Session.SessionID, null, DateTime.MaxValue, timeOut, CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, null);
```

And this in the `Global.asax`

```
if (Session["username"] != null)
    {
        var cacheKey = Session["username"].ToString();
        if ((string) HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKey] != Session.SessionID) LogOut();
    }
```

Comment: Where in Global.asax?In which method?

Comment: Can't  remember at the moment but I can check in a few hours