# Only one login per user in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am working on one web application in which i want to make sure that website allow only one login per user at a time on one browser only.It means if a user is logged in from chrome than that user can not log in from internet explorer or any other browser from the same id at a time.
If he tries to log in from another browser than a message should be displayed saying he is already logged in from a browser and if he wants to continue in another browser than he should get automatically logout from the first one.

Please suggest code for this in asp.net.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow only a single login session per user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25359851/allow-only-a-single-login-session-per-user)

Answer (score -1):

You need to have `status` column in your table and make its datatype `boolean`, so When a user logged in update that status into `true`, and when a user logged out then update status into `false`. Whenever a user try to login then you need to check `status` for that user, if status already true, show a `message` that a user already logged in, if false, then allow for login.

Comment: Thanks but i want that If user tries to log in from another browser than a message should be displayed saying he is already logged in from a browser and if he wants to continue in another browser than he should get automatically logout from the first one.

Comment: yeah, this should work for all browsers. When a user try to login from other browser or other device and he already logged in, just show a message and this message must have 2 buttons, a button for example `log out from other device` and a button for `cancel`. If a user click `log out from other device` then  logout from first one by updating status column into false...

Comment: I gave you the idea already and it is the answer for your question..if you have need something else then please make it as a new question

Comment: Saif, your answer is poor.  and gives no information.